# How to set up the thread.Timer without a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer

I am working on my code to set up the timer. I want to set up the `Timer` without creating the function.

Here is what I use:

```
def hello(self):
    print "hello, world"
    self.getControl(MyPlayer.Control_EPG_ID).setVisible(False)

def onAction(self, action):
    if action.getId() == ACTION_MOVE_DOWN:
       t = threading.Timer(5.0, self.hello)
       t.start()
```

I want to make it to show something is like this:

```
t = threading.Timer(5.0)
t.start()
self.getControl(MyPlayer.Control_EPG_ID).setVisible(False)
```

when I try it, it give me an error. Do you know how I can set up the timer without create a function? if so how?

Comment: If the code to run isn't in a function, where do you want to put it?

Comment: @martineau under the onAction function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to nest `hello()` inside of `onAction()` like this. It will use the `self` argument passed to the outer function:

```
def onAction(self, action):
    def hello():
        print "hello, world"
        self.getControl(MyPlayer.Control_EPG_ID).setVisible(False)

    if action.getId() == ACTION_MOVE_DOWN:
       t = threading.Timer(5.0, hello)
       t.start()
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to use the timer with the seconds without the thread and a function like `hello`.  How I can do that?

Comment: The way you have it in your question ought to work both ways (via `Timer` and for direct calls). Suggest that you edit your question and add the full traceback you're getting (not just "it give me an error").

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)   # delays for 5 seconds
```

Comment: I have used it but it will stop the execution working which I need to delay the execution to 5 seconds. Any idea what i should use instead of a function?

Comment: Now im confused by what you are asking.  If you just need to delay the script for 5 seconds before executing something this should work. Also why are you against functions?

Comment: Because I want to use `self.getControl(MyPlayer.Control_EPG_ID).setVisible(False)
` under OnAction function.